# Use exposed filters to reorder nodes?

Tags: views

Just wondering whether I can use exposed filters to re-order a list of nodes rather than eliminating ones that don't fit the desired criteria.

E.g. If I filter for 'Monday' and have a list of nodes [Sunday, Saturday, Friday, Thursday, Wednesday, Tuesday, Monday], then I would like the list of nodes to return as Monday, Sunday, Saturday, Friday, Thursday, Wednesday, Tuesday.

At the moment my result when I filter for the term 'Monday', is just 'Monday'.

Any thoughts?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your display requirements, you might be able to use a table format.  When using a table format, you have the option to set columns to "sortable".

Format section:

[image]

Sorting settings:

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea! What's the next step though? How do I make it sortable in the way I'd like?

Comment: This way would allow you to sort alphabetically, but you just add your fields and select which ones should be sortable in the format settings.  If you needed something other than alphabetical sorting, you would want to write a custom module with a custom views sort handler.

Comment: I might have to do that, as I need sorting by an input.

The user says 'Monday' and I need to bring 'Monday' to the top of the list.

Comment: There are a million jquery sort/filter plugins.  You could likely find one that fits your specific needs and just drop it on top of your existing setup.

Comment: So you're talking not a module, but chucking it in the code instead?

Comment: Liam, that's what I would do. I've frequently created an additional, hidden table column that contains concatenated or calculated values, and I set that column to be the default sort (the radio button on the right side of Patrick's picture.

In your case, I suppose I'd give the days numeric values starting from Monday and sort by those. (Check out [Bergmark's answer here][1] for a good way to do that.)
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11497447